# Why is my JavaScript not working? It seems to be trouble with my RegEx, but I cannot figure it out

Tags: javascript

As is, if you run this in a browser, it will not work. However, if you were to comment out the first "var rgbArray" and uncomment the second "var rgbArray" then the script will work.

Why will the first way not work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var rgbColorString = "rgb(60, 59, 110)";
            var rgbArray = parseRGBColor(rgbColorString);
            // var rgbArray = [60, 59, 110]
            convertRGBToHEX(rgbArray);

            function parseRGBColor(rgbColorString){
                var colorStringMatch = rgbColorString.match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g);
                return colorStringMatch;
            }

            function convertRGBToHEX(rgbArray){
                document.write("rgbArray: " + rgbArray + "<br>");
                var hexColor = "";
                for(var i=0; i<rgbArray.length; i++){
                    hexColor = hexColor + convertToHexString(rgbArray[i]);
                }
            }

            function convertToHexString(base10Color){
                document.write("Color In: " + base10Color + " => ");
                var convertedColor = (base10Color < 16) ? ("0" + base10Color.toString(16)) : base10Color.toString(16);
                document.write("Color Out: " + convertedColor + "<br>");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just below the line where you're setting `rgbArray`, add this: `console.log(rgbArray)`. What do you see in the console?

Comment: The important part: `console.log(typeof base10Color)`

Comment: In one case you are passing `[60, 59, 110]`, in the case with the regex you are passing `["60", "59", "110"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexes always return their matches as strings, even when the matched part was numerical.
Hence when you call `.toString(16)` on the array elements, their value stays exactly the same.

You need to change `convertToHexString` to convert them to integers first, preferably using `parseInt`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var rgbColorString = "rgb(60, 59, 110)";
            var rgbArray = parseRGBColor(rgbColorString);
            // var rgbArray = [60, 59, 110]
            convertRGBToHEX(rgbArray);

            function parseRGBColor(rgbColorString){
                var colorStringMatch = rgbColorString.match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g);
                return colorStringMatch;
            }

            function convertRGBToHEX(rgbArray){
                document.write("rgbArray: " + rgbArray + "<br>");
                for(var i=0; i<rgbArray.length; i++){
                    convertToHexString(rgbArray[i]);
                }
            }

            function convertToHexString(base10Color){
                document.write("Color In: " + base10Color + " => ");
                var convertedColor = (base10Color < 16 ? "0" : "" ) + parseInt(base10Color).toString(16);
                document.write("Color Out: " + convertedColor + "<br>");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if `convertToHexString` doesn't return anything, the for loop that calls `hexColor` + `convertToHexString...` keeps getting unefined.

Answer (score 2):

**The first:**

```
  var rgbArray = parseRGBColor(rgbColorString);
  //=> ["60","59","110"]
```

will return an array of string.

**The Second:**

```
  var rgbArray = [60, 59, 110]
```

is a array of integers

Answer (score -1):

You need to do two things:

- Return the value from `convertToHexString`
- Use an int value instead of a string in `convertToHexString`

[Working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/sibuvicasi/edit?html,output)

```
var rgbColorString = "rgb(60, 59, 110)";
var rgbArray = parseRGBColor(rgbColorString);
// var rgbArray = [60, 59, 110]
convertRGBToHEX(rgbArray);

function parseRGBColor(rgbColorString){
  var colorStringMatch = rgbColorString.match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g);
  return colorStringMatch;
}

function convertRGBToHEX(rgbArray){
  document.write("rgbArray: " + rgbArray + "<br>");
  var hexColor = "";
  for(var i=0; i<rgbArray.length; i++){
    hexColor = hexColor + convertToHexString(rgbArray[i]);
  }
  document.write("final hex color:" + hexColor);
}

function convertToHexString(base10Color){
  base10Color = parseInt(base10Color);
  document.write("Color In: " + base10Color + " => ");
  var convertedColor = (base10Color < 16) ? ("0" + base10Color.toString(16)) : base10Color.toString(16);
  document.write("Color Out: " + convertedColor + "<br>");
  return convertedColor;
}
```

Comment: Would usually be good practice, but that's not the issue here. The function is only supposed to print the calculated values, and it does that just fine.

Comment: Yes, but your for loop needs to result of `convertToHexString` in order to append the values to the `hexColor` variable.